# Help with object array syntax C#

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax

I have an object array that has 8 entries in it from value 0 to 7. All of the values are pretty standard, but the value in the [7, 0] spot is a string and for [7, 1] it is another object with two entries, [0, 0] and [0, 1].

My question is, I am trying to assign the object in the [7, 1] spot to a separate object array and then am pulling the [0, 1] string value from that object. My syntax for assigning the 7th spot array to another array keeps coming up null though. What is the correct syntax for either
A) Assigning that object to a usable object
B) Or just flat out pulling the value from the [7, 1] array and the [0, 1] inner object to a string?

I am using this right now: `object[,] checkCD  = param[7, 1] as object[,];`
which is coming up null, I would rather just get the string from the inner object flat out but help!

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you post some code.

Comment: What code? I mean, it's an object array with an object in the [7, 1] spot instead of a string, int, etc value. I would think that should explain everything. Inside that object is a string in the [0, 1] spot I need. Like for real, what can I post that would make that any clearer, do you really need to see the variable names of the things assigned to it to understand what I'm talking about? If so you probably can't help me anyway.

Comment: Maybe if you made the types more explicit. It looks like you're talking about nested multidimensional arrays but it's not entirely clear. It doesn't matter what the variable names are but type declaration and sample data can help. It doesn't matter how well you write, English isn't anywhere near as exact as code.

Comment: As an aside: problems like this is why classes should be preferred to arrays for structured data (when possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I could understand of your question, if after executing this line

```
object[,] checkCD = param[7, 1] as object[,];
```

`checkCD` is null, then it means that `param[7, 1]` does not contain an `object[,]`, but something of another type (or null).

Try instead

```
object x = param[7, 1];
```

and check what's the type of `x` - maybe you just put in [7,1] the wrong thing. If after this, x is null then it means that `param[7, 1]` is really null.

Comment: This worked but I changed it a little to be

`object[] checkArray = param[7, 1] as object[];`

since the original code gave me an error in the confines of my program. TY

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, am i missing anyting.

```
object[,] array1 = new object[8,2];
            
            array1[7,1] = new object[1,2] { {"00","01"}};
            array1[7,0] = new StringBuilder("Initialized");

         object[,] seventthobj = (object[,])array1[7, 1];
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assignment should be `param[7,1] = new object[,] {{value, "string"}};`.